# Is there a way to make toilet porcelain dirt and stain resistant?

Tags: toilet, cleaning

I'm sure this problem is present all around the world as toilet brushes are ubiquitous in every toilet I've ever been to. But this is the 21st century, there must be a better solution!

Is there a smart way to make porcelain non-sticky? How do I get rid of the toilet brush once and for good?

Comment: Do you mean inside the bowl? Or on the seat? If the latter, clean the toilet! If the former, that's due more to the water in your region than the porcelain surface.

Comment: @DA01 inside the bowl

Comment: That has more to do with the mineral deposits the water leaves on the surface. I'd look at cleaning products that are sold to help with mineral deposits.

Comment: For an older toilet, I'd be worried that mineral deposits over the years have harmed the original glazing, making the issue that much worse - if that's even a possibility.  I know the glazing on my sink is shot, but the toilet doesn't get many pots and pans scraping around in it.

Comment: There are toilet cleaners containing teflon (I found some results by googling "teflon toilet cleaner") which are supposed to make the porcelain repel stains. Won't completely eliminate the need for a brush, but could reduce the need to clean frequently.

Comment: So you are looking for Lotus effect surfaces or the like?

Comment: Somethings just require a little mechanical action.  If it was possible and affordable it would be marketed like crazy.  In our convenience culture we live in, this would sell like hotcakes.

Comment: If your toilet has been aggressively over-cleaned the surface may be damaged, which will make cleaning more difficult - the solution to which is a new toilet. I have seen (as a truly bizarre example) an old toilet-cleaning chemical which contained HF (hydrofluoric acid) - extremely dangerous to people and also prone to etching glass (such as the porcelain surface,) so doubly bizarre.

Comment: @Ecnerwal even brand new toilets are not entirely prone to stains, unfortunately.

Comment: The basic problem is most water sources are slightly corrosive to the glass like glazes used to coat toilets. Proprietary glazes on higher end toilets claim to have disinfection or mold/mildew reduction properties, but unless they can withstand chemical and mechanical attack, it is only a partial short term solution. Disinfection is not really the problem.
I stumbled upon one very well known toilet manufacturer R&D website and asked " Why use glazes susceptible to water borne chemical attack?" There was no reply.
Certainly with present surface coating technology, manufacturers can do a better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you would need is a product that will apply a "hydrophobic" coating to your toilet. Hydrophobic means that it will repel water, and make it very difficult for anything to stick to the surface. This would reduce the amount of effort required to keep a toilet clean.

At this point, there are not many products on the market with these properties which are available to consumers. So far I have only been able to locate one of these products.

The following is not a product endorsement. I do not have any affiliation with the manufacturer, and am only listing an example. I have also not tried this product myself, but there are videos online of this in action, and it appears to be very effective at repelling water.

http://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/neverwet/neverwet-kit/

Comment: I'm not sure if a hydrophobic coating is the most appropriate material here, since it's not water that we're trying to repel from the porcelain.

Comment: @JohnReez the toilet in JPhi's answer most likely has a similar coating. I don't know of any residential toilets which have this yet, but I suppose that could change in the future. The coating not only repels water, but dirt and grease as well. There are a couple of videos showing what happens to dirt when it is sprayed onto a surface that has the coating on it on the site.

Comment: @JohnReez In general, hydrophobic materials do not accumulate things that get on them dissolved in water. Note how longer a car window stays clean after you visit a car wash with a good after-treatment (waxes mostly), as opposed to when you only wash it by water.

Comment: There are hydrophobic coatings available to consumers, such as Ultra Ever Dry. Might do the trick as far as keeping the toilet clean, but there would be unintended consequences with changing spray patterns.  Plenty of videos online about hydrophobic coatings cities are applying to walls to deter public urination, I imagine the effect would be similar inside a toilet. Here is one such video: https://youtu.be/J5iCb6RtreM

Comment: Rustoleum Never Wet is very susceptible to physical damage. A couple good scrubs with a toilet brush will noticeably reduce its repellency.  I'm not familiar with Ultra Ever Dry.  RainX or a good wax coating may help but the toilet would need to be clean and dry for best application, and would need to be reapplied periodically.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, it has [been done](http://www.sloanvalve.com/Our_Products/Waterfree_Urinals.aspx).

[image]

I've seen these urinals in several locations.  The idea is that they are treated so the urine all goes down the drain with no water at all.  They still need to be regularly cleaned because of all the random stuff people put in urinals, but they almost eliminate water usage and are still very sanitary.

Hopefully we aren't very far away from seeing this technology in standard residential toilets to make them cleaner (but not necessarily remove water from the equation).

Comment: Admittedly, I sort of mis-read the question.  This is and example of a toilet being made "less sticky", but not really something the OP can do at home.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly valid. If such toilets were on sale, the answer could be 'buy a new toilet', which is also valid :)

Comment: Unfortunately, a urinal is not a toilet, and the design of these seems less of a "treatment" and more a modified trap and a replaceable filter cartridge to catch "sediment", and would be rendered completely and horribly useless if waste other than urine is put in it. I suspect OP's main need for a brush is not related to urine.

Comment: You're right about "other materials".  The one's I've seen have a little sign above them saying how they have special coatings and a waste valve/cartridge to make them water-free.

Answer (score 1):

Since the toilet is porous in nature, even some of the new ones do not have a coating on them.  You can treat your toilet like the windshield of your car with a coating of rain-x or similar product that repels water, or as others state a sealant or silicone-like coating that will close the porous surface of the toilet.

I have purchased more expensive toilets and with there special coating no sticking takes place or very very little.  For example, Toto has proprietary glazes that are options on many of its toilets (called Sanagloss or CeFiONtect) that do this.